# Check if the sum of fields are greater than 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

What I try to achieve to give alert if the sum of first values are greater than 100 if not third value has to be calculated  like this;
3th textbox= 100- 1st textbox- 2th textbox

It works well at the beginning. When I type 100 for 1st textbox then 20 for 2nd I get error then I enter 80-30 I get again alert but then third times when I enter 50-30 I again get error  but actually it shouldnt give error it should write in third textbox 20

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // calc
    jQuery("#custom-419").on("change", function() {
        var vorOrt = $(this).val();
        jQuery("#custom-420").on("change", function() {
            var vorOrt2 = $(this).val();
            var sum = 0;
            sum += parseInt(vorOrt);
            sum += parseInt(vorOrt2);
            console.log($('#sum').val());
            if (sum <= 100) {
                var onWeb = 100 - vorOrt;
                onWeb = onWeb - vorOrt2;
                jQuery("#421").val(onWeb);
            } else {
                window.alert("The sum of values can not be more than 100!");
                $('#custom-419').val("");
                $('#custom-420').val("");
                $('#custom-421').val("");
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Please put your code as a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Because all the other answers contains jQuery, I though it may be helpful to provide a vanilla JavaScript solution. ***Keep in mind that solution is for modern browser only!***

```js
function calc() {
  const counters = [...document.querySelectorAll('.counter')];
  const total = document.querySelector('.total');
  const sum = counters.reduce((a, b) => a += parseInt(b.value) || 0, 0);

  total.value = sum;

  if (sum <= 100) return;

  alert("The sum of values can not be more than 100!");
  counters.forEach(x => x.value = '');
  total.value = '';
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.counter'), x => x.addEventListener('keyup', calc));
```

```html
<div>
  result has to be less then or equal 100
</div>
<input class="counter" id="#custom-419" /> +
<input class="counter" id="#custom-420" /> =
<input class="total" id="#custom-421" disabled />
```

### Explanation

Because you didn't show us your current html, I made it simple. So no explanation required I guess.

What happens in that JS solution is pretty straight forward.

In the last line both input with the call `counter` are getting an `EventListener` to fire on [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup). *You may keep the `change` event instead...*

In the `calc` function all values of the counters get parsed to int and aggregated to `sum`. The rest of the code is nothing special.

---

As the above solution is for modern browsers only (ES6+), here are two more for older browsers:

#### IE11+ Support ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0m4wqx4L/))

```
function calc() {
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  const total = document.querySelector('.total');
  const sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(counters, function(a, b) {
    return a += parseInt(b.value) || 0;
  }, 0);

  total.value = sum;

  if (sum <= 100) return;

  alert("The sum of values can not be more than 100!");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(counters, function(x) {
    x.value = '';
  });
  total.value = '';
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.counter'), function(x) {
    x.addEventListener('keyup', calc);
});
```

#### IE9+ Support ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2oq80hwu/))

*I made two more function for this example to make it a bit more readable.*

```
function calc() {
  var counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
  var total = document.querySelector('.total');
  var sum = getSum(counters);

  total.value = sum;

  if (sum <= 100) return;

  alert("The sum of values can not be more than 100!");
  clearCounters(counters);
  total.value = '';
}

function getSum(counters) {
    var result = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
        result += parseInt(counters[i].value) || 0;
    }

    return result;
}

function clearCounters(counters) {
    for(var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
        counters[i].value = '';
    }
}

var _counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
for(var i = 0; i < _counters.length; i++) {
    _counters[i].addEventListener('keyup', calc);
}
```

Comment: I love vanilla solutions! Very good. Better use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `[].forEach`. The latter will create an unnecessary Array object. With the former option you just borrow Array's `forEach` to iterate over an arrayish object like a nodelist.

Comment: Also to go for the win! Also provide a solution that would still work in older browsers using no *ES6* methods.

Comment: Last one: you could optimize by only using `reduce`: `const sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(counters, function(acc, val){
    return (parseInt(acc.value, 10) || 0) + (parseInt(val.value, 10) || 0);
  });`

Comment: You're right but in this case `acc` does not have to be parsed. I'll update my answer somewhen later. *I'm not on the computer anymore.*

Answer (score 1):

Why nesting the 2 event functions ?

Try this :

```js
var vorOrt = 0;
var vorOrt2 = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#custom-419').on('change', function() {
    vorOrt = $(this).val();
    checkInputs();
  });

  $('#custom-420').on('change', function() {
    vorOrt2 = $(this).val();
    checkInputs();
  });
});

function checkInputs() {

  var sum = 0;
  sum += parseInt(vorOrt, 10);
  sum += parseInt(vorOrt2, 10);

  if (sum <= 100) {
    var onWeb = 100 - vorOrt - vorOrt2;
    $("#custom-421").val(onWeb);
  } else {
    window.alert('The sum of values can not be more than 100!');
    $('#custom-419').val('');
    $('#custom-420').val('');
    $('#custom-421').val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="counter" id="custom-419" type="number" />
<input class="counter" id="custom-420" type="number" />
<input class="total" id="custom-421" type="number" />
```

Comment: Good answer! Try to avoid introducing global variables. They clutter the global scope and can interfere with other parts of a more complex code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following solution. It uses jQuery's `each`.

1. What I did is attach the same function to every input by using a descriptive class name: `counter`. We can easily get all the input using the selector `input.counter` and add an onchange event with only one line of code.
2. After that the generic function `testIfMoreThanHundred` will iterate over all the element using `each` and sum the values into a variable.
3. after that it's just a simple `if` check to see if the value if more than a hundred.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // calc
  $("input.counter").on("change", testIfMoreThanHundred);

});

//let's make a generic function shall we:
function testIfMoreThanHundred() {
  var sum = 0;
  //get the elements and use each to iterate over them
    $("input.counter").each(function() {
    var number = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    
    //test if value is a number, if not use 0
    if (!isNaN(number)) {
      sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    } else {
      sum += 0;
    }

  });

if (sum > 100)
  {
    alert("The sum can't be greater than a 100");
    $("input.counter").val(""); //empty the values
    $("input.total").val("");
  }
else
{
$("input.total").val(100 - sum); //show value in third box
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="counter" id="custom-419" type="number" />
<input class="counter" id="custom-420" type="number" />
<input class="total" id="custom-421" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once change function is inside the other, which is not necessary, Also reset the value of `sum` when alert is thrown

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0; // initializing sum

  function calSum(val) {
    sum += val; // will add the values
    console.log(sum)
    if (sum <= 100) {
      var onWeb = 100 - sum;
      $("#custom-421").val(onWeb);
    } else {
      alert("The sum of values can not be more than 100!");
      $('#custom-419').val("");
      $('#custom-420').val("");
      $('#custom-421').val("");
      sum = 0;
    }
  }
  $("#custom-419").on("change", function() {
    calSum(parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
  });
  $("#custom-420").on("change", function() {
    calSum(parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="custom-419">
<input type="text" id="custom-420">
<input type="text" id="custom-421">
```

Comment: Great answer, one little problem. Every time `calSum` is called upon it will keep adding until it reaches a hundred. It should recalculate if both inputs reach a hundred every time `calSum` is called starting from `0`. Next to the fact that this solution introduces an unnecessary global variable.